# Explode by delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, explode

I have a little question.

Right now I have a string which looks like that :

```
:value1, GARBAGE :value2, :value3
```

And another string which looks like that :

```
:value4 MAYBE GARBAGE :value5 GARBAGE :value6
```

How can I manage, within the same function to get all the values in an array, that are beginning with ':'

Like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
)
```

...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php + simple regular expression …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use regular expressions.

Here 2 examples that works :

```
preg_match_all('/:([^ ,]+)/', $input, $matches);
```

Or

```
preg_match_all('/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $input, $matches);
```

Replace `$input` with your string and results in correct form will be in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<?php
  $str = ':value1, GARBAGE :value2, :value3 :value4 MAYBE GARBAGE :value5 GARBAGE :value6';
  preg_match_all ('/\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\w,]*/' , $str, $matches);

  print_r($matches[1]);
?>
</pre>
```